# failed to obtain node locks, tried [/usr/share/elasticsearch/data];

Tags: elasticsearch, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

i am trying to run an elasticsearch container inside an aws ecs fargate task (container). i have mounted an efs volume on container and want to map /usr/share/elasticsearch/data of elasticsearch to this volume. but when i run the task i get the following error[image: cloudwatch logs]
since it's an ecs fargate task i can not access the underlying container (instance) so that if it's a permissions issue i can change those permissions on the run.

when i try to change the permissions through ecs container definition i.e
Entry point ["sh","-c"]
Command ["chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
[image: docker container definition]
i get permission denied error and when i use sudo with chown i get "sudo not found"

is there any solution to this i am stuck with it and i need data to persist so /usr/share/elasticsearch/data must be mapped to efs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since it's an ecs fargate task i can not access the underlying container (instance)

Actually you can, using [ECS Exec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html)

However, it sounds like your ECS Task simply doesn't have the permissions required to access the EFS volume. To fix that, you should crate an [EFS Access Point](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-access-points.html) for the EFS volume, configure the EFS mount settings in the ECS task to use the EFS Access Point, and configure the Access Point to use a specific Unix `OwnerUid` and `OwnerGiD`, and Permissions for all connections.

You should also make sure your ECS [Task IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) has the following EFS permissions:

```
"elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
"elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite",
"elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess"
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, this was helpful, i already had permissions set for the task role, i was just missing the access point configurations on efs.

Comment: one small question tho, i am running a single container for now and it's working fine, i stop and restarted it and data persisted. but when i started another container with same task def it gave me the same error as above, only one container works at this time.

Comment: Only one is going to be able to obtain a lock at a time. If you want to run scalable ElasticSearch you should really consider the AWS OpenSearch service, or purchasing ElasticCloud through the AWS marketplace.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the help :)